# "Magical" intel c++ compiler : what happened?

Tags: c++, intel, icc

I am on *nix. Have this simple c++ code in `looptest.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
      double sum = 0.0;
      int n ;
      std::cout << "n ?" << std::endl;
      std::cin >> n ;
      clock_t t_start = clock();
      for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
      {
            sum+= static_cast<double>(i);
      }
      clock_t t_end = clock();
      clock_t diff = t_end - t_start;
      double diffd = static_cast<double>(diff)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      std::cout << diffd << " seconds." << std::endl;
      sum*=1.0;
      return 0;
}
```

compiled with the intel c++ compiler (icpc (ICC) 14.0.4 20140805, 2013) as follows :

```
/opt/intel/bin/icpc looptest.cpp -o looptest
```

When I test it, I have the following curious result :

```
My-MacBook-Air:tmp11 XXXX$ ./looptest 
n ?
10000
4e-06 seconds.
My-MacBook-Air:tmp11 XXXX$ ./looptest 
n ?
100000
3e-06 seconds.
My-MacBook-Air:tmp11 XXXX$ ./looptest 
n ?
1000000
3e-06 seconds.
My-MacBook-Air:tmp11 XXXX$ ./looptest 
n ?
1000000000
2e-06 seconds.
My-MacBook-Air:tmp11 XXXX$ ./looptest 
n ?
4294967295
3e-06 seconds.
```

Strange, isn't it ? What happened here ? Of course, compiling with gnu-5.2's `g++` instead of `icpc` gives an expected result (time increasing when n increases.)

Comment: There's never anything _magical_ involved in c++ programming. Skip that concept, get serious instead!

Comment: He put "magical" in quotes to indicate that it isn't really magical.

Comment: Try g++ with -ffast-math too

Comment: Have you looked at the code icc generates?  Does it, for example, [figure out that you're calculating the sum of integers from 0 to n - 1, and just calculate (n-1)*(n-2)/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)?

Comment: The optimizer was able to determine that you aren't doing anything with the result of the computation, hence it probably just removed your loop.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Undefined behaviour can lead to some pretty magical post-optimization behaviour, though.

Comment: Put values strictly lower that int max to avoid integer overflow. Same behaviour of course.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg 1000000000 shouldn't really overflow `int` nowadays…

Comment: @harold `-ffast-math` gives a time roughly linear in `n`.

Comment: Discussing UB is pretty useless!

Comment: @GuyHarris I know this, but I'd pretty amazed of a compiler optimizing this way. ;-) I'm not an assembly expert, but I'll compared assemblies for my code and the code from Kay's answer to see if there "the same".

Comment: Try printing the result - even if the compiler wasn't clever enough to figure that out, it was able to figure out that you never did anything with the result of the loop, as others have noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sum` is nowhere read, so all assignments to the variable were removed. This made the for-loop empty, so it was removed, too. Hence what remains is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
      int n ;
      std::cout << "n ?" << std::endl;
      std::cin >> n ;
      clock_t t_start = clock();
      clock_t t_end = clock();
      clock_t diff = t_end - t_start;
      double diffd = static_cast<double>(diff)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      std::cout << diffd << " seconds." << std::endl;
      return 0;
}
```

Effectively you measure how fast a single call to `clock()` is.

Look at the compiled code to figure out the optimizations the compiler did. GCC "should" be able to do the same optimization, but it will only do it if you add the parameter `-O` (`-O2`, `-O3`, `-Os`) to the invocation.

Comment: Indeed, adding something involving `sum` after (like aksing for a factor and multiplying sum by it after) yields a O(n) time. And `-O`'s, in the case of the initial code, yield to the same result. One question though : `sum` is indeed nowhere read, but appears bracketed between two times that are used to produce a time gap which is printed after. Why doesn't the compiler detect this ? Reformulation : how smart is the compiler ? ;-)

Comment: @user10000100_u: Modern optimizing compilers are very smart. For example see [Data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis).

Comment: @user10000100_u The compiler is smart about producing the correct functional result as fast as possible (or any other optimization you tell it to do), not about detecting some side effect you want to measure. For all it cares, you are interested in measuring the overhead of `clock` calls.